In Golang using Excelize package, how can I align a picture in a center position by using the AddPicture function?
I'm using excelize in golang, and I inserted a picture into a cell, but it's align left. I think it's the way of inserting the picture by excelize, which is add picture over cell. I couldn't change the alignment by setting the cell style.
if err := f.AddPicture("Sheet1", "A1", "IMAGE.png",
    &excelize.GraphicOptions{
        AutoFit:         true,
        LockAspectRatio: true,
    }); err != nil {
    ......
}


I believe that the picture only follows the cell alignment when its placed in the cell; this is a relatively new feature (linked article says it's still rolling out) and I don't think excelize supports this yet. Please include the code you are using to add the picture.

@Brits I've added the code I used for adding the picture.

A picture inserted like that will not follow the cells style (you can check this in Excel itself). If you have a new release Excel will give you the option to "Place In Cell", after which the picture will follow the cell format. I cannot see any support for this type of picture in Excelize (and GetPictures does not return any info on them). I'd suggest positioniting your image using another technique (note that Excel alternatives like Google Docs and like LibreOffice don't yet support the picture in cell functionality).
